Replacing a cosine by a sine in a differential equation
My question comes from a physics textbook: Classical Mechanics by John R. Taylor. In the section on driven damped oscillations, the author solves the differential equation $$\ddot{x} + 2\beta\dot{x} + w_0^2x = f_0\cos(\omega t)$$ by using a "trick".

He argues that there must exist a corresponding equation $$\ddot{y} + 2\beta\dot{y} + w_0^2y = f_0\sin(\omega t)$$.

He defines $z = x + iy$ and adds the second equation multiplied by i to the first to get $$\ddot{z} + 2\beta\dot{z} + w_0^2z = f_0e^{i\omega t}$$

Finally, he solves for $z$ and takes the real part to get $x$.


I'm confused about the first step. How does he know that the second equation exists? What would be the difference between x and y? cos and sin are phase shifted but he adds the two equations so t is the same in both? Is there a visual/intuitive way to understand what is happening? I'm just confused in general with this derivation...
Edit: What I'm really confused about is how the author knows that the second equation must have a solution if the first one has a solution.
Thank you for all the answers! My conclusion is that I don't need to worry too much about the existence of a solution for $y(t)$ I can just solve for $z(t)$ and argue that the real part must be equal to $x(t)$.

What do you mean by "the second equation exists"? It is is clear that $z$ is a solution of the 3rd equation iff its real and imaginary part are respectively solutions of the 1st and 2nd one. To conclude that all (real) solutions of the 1st equation can be obtained this way, you only need to check that the 3rd equation has at least one (complex) solution, which implies that the 2nd one has at least one (real) solution.

All equations exist. The question is if they have solutions. Here, he has shown it has a solution, by taking the imaginary part of his complex solution.

Thank you for the clarification. The author states that the second equation has a solution because the first one has a solution. He then used that claim to construct the third equation. I think what confuses me is how he knows the second equation has a solution.

What do you mean by "the second equation exists"? It is is clear that $z$ is a solution of the 3rd equation iff its real and imaginary part are respectively solutions of the 1st and 2nd one. To conclude that all (real) solutions of the 1st equation can be obtained this way, you only need to check that the 3rd equation has at least one (complex) solution, which implies that the 2nd one has at least one (real) solution.
Update, after your edit:

"the second equation must have a solution if the first one has a solution" because il $x(t)$ is a solution of the 1st equation then $y(t):=x\left(t-\frac\pi{2\omega}\right)$ is a solution of the 2nd one.
if you "just solve for $z(t)$ and argue that the real part must be equal to $x(t)$", or better worded: argue that the real part must be a solution $x(t)$ of the 1st equation, you are not sure that all (real) solutions of the 1st equation are obtained this way. To complete the resolution, you "need to worry too much about the existence of a solution for $y(t)$": if such a (real) $y$ exists then every (real) solution $x$ (of the 1st) is the real part of a solution $z$ (of the 3rd), namely: $z:=x+iy$.
there are two ways to fill the gap:

Taylor's way, saying that if some function $x$ is a solution of the 1st then $z(t):=x(t)+ix\left(t-\frac\pi{2\omega}\right)$ is a solution of the 3rd,
a perhaps less tricky way, consisting in solving explicitely the 3rd first, thereby proving the existence of at least one solution $z_0$, then taking the imaginary part $y_0$ of your $z_0$, and saying that if some function $x$ is a solution of the 1st then $z:=x+iy_0$ is a solution of the 3rd.




Specifically, the author wrote: "Solving [the first equation] is greatly simplified by the following trick: For any solution of
[the first equation], there must be a solution of the same equation, but with the cosine on the right
replaced by a sine function. (After all, these two differ only by a shift in the origin of
time.) Accordingly, there must also be a function y(t) that satisfies [the second equation]." This is what I don't understand.

@AzizBenbachir Taylor means that if $x(t)$ solves the first equation, then $y(t) = x(t-\pi/2\omega))$ - that is, shifting time by a change of variable converts the first equation to the second. Arguing from the premise that a solution to the first equation exists is a bit confusing: what he means is if a solution to the first exists, then there must be a solution to the second by this time-shifting argument. cont.

Mathematically, there isn't really a need to presuppose the existence of a solution here. You can just say "I can solve the equation for $z$" (which you demonstrate by, well, solving the equation for $z$), set $x$ to be the real part, and show $x$ (now a specific, concrete function) solves the original equation: thus the existence of a solution is proved and you have a specific example, namely $x$. Taylor's wording is a bit circuitous, but that's basically what he's getting at.

@GyuEunLee I think I get it, thank you!

Slightly more generally, if $z$ satisfies a differential equation $a(t) \ddot{z} + b(t) \dot{z} + c(t) z = f(t)$ where $a(t), b(t), c(t)$ are real,
then $x = \text{Re}(z)$ and $y = \text{Im}(z)$ satisfy the differential equations
$a(t) \ddot{x} + b(t) \dot{x} + c(t) x = \text{Re}(f(t))$ and $a(t) \ddot{y} + b(t) \dot{y} + c(t) y = \text{Im}(f(t))$  respectively.
